# Get XML payload size in MB

Tags: mule, dataweave, mule-studio, mulesoft, mule4

I need to check the size of incoming payload that is in the XML format in MB. And if size is over certain MB (example 50 MB) I need to route the flows using choice router. I have issues checking the size of the incoming payload. I tried writing the below code in dataweave but its giving me errors:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var someXml = read(payload, "application/xml")
---
{
Size: sizeOf(write(someXml, "application/xml"))
}
```

Below is the sample request XML that I am trying to read and check its size:

```
<root>
    <simple>
        <account>
            <No>123456789</No>
            <IDNumber>129</IDNumber>
        </simple>
    </account>
</root>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use

```
sizeOf(payload.^raw)
```

This will return the size of the underlying stream without the need of parsing or re write